# How to parse a malformed xml (ofx) with ofx4j?

Tags: java, xml, ofx

i am desperatly trying to use the following library : [ofx4j](http://ofx4j.sourceforge.net/userguide.html). But the documentation relative to parsing an ofx file is a bit lite. It says : If you've got a file or other stream resource, you can read it using an instance of net.sf.ofx4j.io.OFXReader

Ok but how do i do ?

It also states the following: if you want to unmarshal the OFX directly to a Java object, use the net.sf.ofx4j.io.AggregateUnmarshaller.

Fine, but that's a bit complicated for me. Is there something obvious that i missed ? When i try to use the unmarshaller, it asks me to implement an interface.

Could someone point me to an online resource explaining the bits that i am missing ? Or the best, what do you understand from the previous statements relative to the ofxreader and the unmarshaller ?

Please, don't bash me, I am learning java with the playframework and i would really appreciate to be able to parse those ofx files.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a plain old tutorial, but there's sample code in the [test](http://ofx4j.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ofx4j/trunk/src/test/java/net/sf/ofx4j/) directory that illustrates `OFXReader` and `AggregateUnmarshaller`.

The phrase "an instance of [`net.sf.ofx4j.io.OFXReader`](http://ofx4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/ofx4j/io/OFXReader.html)" means one of the known implementing classes", such as [`NanoXMLOFXReader`](http://ofx4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/ofx4j/io/nanoxml/NanoXMLOFXReader.html), which is [tested here](http://ofx4j.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ofx4j/trunk/src/test/java/net/sf/ofx4j/io/nanoxml/TestNanoXMLOFXReader.java?revision=17&view=markup). A test for [`AggregateUnmarshaller`](http://ofx4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/ofx4j/io/AggregateMarshaller.html) is [here](http://ofx4j.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ofx4j/trunk/src/test/java/net/sf/ofx4j/io/TestUnmarshalling.java?revision=17&view=markup).

The [API](http://ofx4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) and [mail](https://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=232500) archives are good resources, too. It looks like a lot of [institutions](http://www.ofxhome.com/index.php/home/directory) participate.

Comment: Thank you so much you totally made my day... I'm so ashamed that i missed the unit tests.

Thanks a lot for you directions.

Answer (score 3):

For those that stumble on this like I did when I couldn't get the expected results from the AggregateUnmarshaller... Here is an example.

```
//Using a multipart file, but using a regular file is similar.
public void parse(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
  //Use ResponseEnvelope to start.
  AggregateUnmarshaller<ResponseEnvelope> unmarshaller = new AggregateUnmarshaller<ResponseEnvelope>(
    ResponseEnvelope.class);

  try {
    ResponseEnvelope envelope = unmarshaller.unmarshal(file.getInputStream());
    //Assume we are just interested in the credit card info.  Make sure to cast.
    CreditCardResponseMessageSet messageSet = (CreditCardResponseMessageSet) envelope
      .getMessageSet(MessageSetType.creditcard);

    List<CreditCardStatementResponseTransaction> responses = messageSet.getStatementResponses();
    for (CreditCardStatementResponseTransaction response : responses) {
      CreditCardStatementResponse message = response.getMessage();
      String currencyCode = message.getCurrencyCode();
      List<Transaction> transactions = message.getTransactionList().getTransactions();
      for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
        System.out.println(transaction.getName() + " " + transaction.getAmount() + " "
          + currencyCode);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (OFXParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```