# Implementing OFX specification with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ofx

I am working on a personal project and need to retrieve financial data.  After looking around how this is normally done it seems you can pay lots of money and license a service like Yodlee to get this data for you or you can implement a OFX client like wesabe has to communicate with financial institutions.  Seeing as I don't have lots of money and wouldn't mind the challenge I decided to try to implement the ofx spec (unless one of you can suggest a cheap/free alternative!).

I looked around for some ofx libraries other people have already written for use but didn't find anything that looked too great.  I was wondering if anyone knew if it would be a bad idea to attempt this in Javascript. If there is some awful reason why I shouldn't do this please bring it up.  If there is I'll just do it in Java but I think it would be nice to have it completely in javascript so it can run completely on a client and not through my servers.

Anyways I was hoping for some insight from SO, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about JavaScript, but [OFX4J](http://ofx4j.sourceforge.net/) provides an implementation of [OFX](http://ofx.net/) for Java. This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221608) may offer additional insight.