# writing a simple ofx4j program

Tags: java

I have been using http://ofx4j.sourceforge.net/userguide.html as a guide to write a small java program to download my bank account statement from wells fargo.  I keep getting an error saying Invalid Signon.  I have the right url.  I am using the same password and username as I use to logon to their webpage.  Does anyone have any other simple samples that I could look at or use?

Comment: The banks and other financial institutions I've used all store a cookie in the browser on the first logon. If the cookie isn't there, they ask for _more_ information than username/password, if the cookie is there, they are content with username/password. The thinking being that if you're using your usual computers, you're probably you :) and if you're using a new computer, it might not be you. So your program may need to answer the additional security question and store whatever cookie results from the transaction, so that it can be used in future transactions.

Comment: The test directory has a few examples, mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223418

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I was trying to log into Chase Bank but I was getting an Invalid Signon.
The problem that I had is that I was using the wrong data, oxf4j might have obsolete data
stored for the banks it has stored.
Go to gnucash to get the right updated setting for your bank:
http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/OFX_Direct_Connect_Bank_Settings.
Then you need to create a new BaseFinancialInstitutionData object
like this (this example is for chase credit card):

```
BaseFinancialInstitutionData data =  new BaseFinancialInstitutionData();
data.setFinancialInstitutionId("10898");
data.setOFXURL(new URL("https://ofx.chase.com"));
data.setOrganization("B1");
FinancialInstitutionService service = new FinancialInstitutionServiceImpl();
FinancialInstitution fi = service.getFinancialInstitution(data);
```