# Quickbooks xml schema for transactions

Tags: xml, quickbooks

I went to my online bank account and did an export of my transactions into a format that's supposed to be consumed by Quickbooks.  I've attached a sample response (with fake data) to this question.  My questions are as follows:

1. Is there only a maximum of 1 STMTRS node to each STMTTRNRS node?
2. Is there only a maximum of 1 BANKACCTFROM node to each STMTRS node?
3. Is there only a maximum of 1 BANKTRANLIST node to each STMTRS node?
4. Is there only a maximum of 1 DTSTART node to each BANKTRANLIST node?
5. Is there only a maximum of 1 DTEND node to each BANKTRANLIST node?

Here's the example quickbooks xml document

```
OFXHEADER:100
DATA:OFXSGML
VERSION:102
SECURITY:TYPE1
ENCODING:USASCII
CHARSET:1252
COMPRESSION:NONE
OLDFILEUID:NONE
NEWFILEUID:NONE

<OFX>
 <SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
  <SONRS>
   <STATUS>
    <CODE>0
    <SEVERITY>INFO
    <MESSAGE>OK
   </STATUS>
   <DTSERVER>20131200000000[-5]
   <LANGUAGE>ENG
   <INTU.BID>00015
  </SONRS>
 </SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
 <BANKMSGSRSV1>
  <STMTTRNRS>
   <TRNUID>C0010000000000000
   <STATUS>
    <CODE>0
    <SEVERITY>INFO
    <MESSAGE>OK
   </STATUS>
   <STMTRS>
    <CURDEF>CAD
    <BANKACCTFROM>
     <BANKID>000000000
     <ACCTID>01111111999
     <ACCTTYPE>CHECKING
    </BANKACCTFROM>
    <BANKTRANLIST>
     <DTSTART>20130917120000[-5]
     <DTEND>20131217120000[-5]
     <STMTTRN>
      <TRNTYPE>CREDIT
      <DTPOSTED>20131117100000[-5]
      <TRNAMT>800.00
      <FITID>900000100201309XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      <NAME>Transfer
      <MEMO>WWW TRANSFER - 5693 
     </STMTTRN>
     <STMTTRN>etc...</STMTTRN>
     <STMTTRN>etc...</STMTTRN>
     <STMTTRN>etc...</STMTTRN>
     etc...

    </BANKTRNLIST>
   </STMTRS>
  </STMTTRNRS>
 </BANKMSGSRSV1>
</OFX>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [Open Financial Exchange](http://www.ofx.net/) (OFX).  You can download the OFX DTDs and XSDs [here](http://www.ofx.net/DownloadPage/Downloads.aspx).  The version you have is SGML, not XML, and is 1.0.2 apparently.  Per the OFXBANK.DTD in the [OFX1.0.2.zip](http://www.ofx.net/DownloadPage/Files/ofx102spec.zip):

1. There may be 0 or 1 STMTRS children to STMTTRNRS.
2. There must be 1 BANKACCTFROM child to STMTRS.
3. There may be 0 or more STMTTRN children to BANKTRANLIST.
4. There must be one DTSTART child to BANKTRANLIST.
5. There must be one DTEND child to BANKTRANLIST.

See also [How to parse this OFX file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5731153/290085)